# Rewriting string in .NET CLR heaps using dnlib

Tags: c#, .net, disassembly, dnlib

I need to rewrite strings in #US heap in .NET file. I decided to use [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) that looks like a powerful library to manipulate .NET files. It is underdocumented unfortunately.

I load the file the usual way. The `ModuleDefMD` `Load()` methods seem to be the only way to load the file:

```
ModuleDefMD module = ModuleDefMD.Load("test.dll");
```

Now, the dnlib has `Writer` namespace that suggests it should be used to write to the .NET structures. It contains [`USHeap` class](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/59281085c10dc6f0ef497893821c8a8629c81349/src/DotNet/Writer/USHeap.cs#L13) that looks promising.

It seems the Writer needs to create metadata that it can work on:

```
dnlib.DotNet.Writer.MetaData metadata = dnlib.DotNet.Writer.MetaData.Create(module, null, null, null);
```

In the USHeap class there is [`SetRawData()` method](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/59281085c10dc6f0ef497893821c8a8629c81349/src/DotNet/Writer/USHeap.cs#L154) with [description](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/59281085c10dc6f0ef497893821c8a8629c81349/src/DotNet/Writer/IOffsetHeap.cs#L25) "Overrides what value should be written to the heap". The rest is unclear, let's use it anyway to write 3 raw arbitrary bytes. According to the CLI standard, the first valid offset is 1:

```
byte[] raw_data = { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 };   // "abc"
uint offset = 1;   // the least valid offset in #US heap
metadata.USHeap.SetRawData(offset, raw_data);
```

[dnlib Examples](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/tree/59281085c10dc6f0ef497893821c8a8629c81349/Examples) show how to write the file:

```
module.Write("test-out.dll");
```

This code compiles and runs without errors. Unfortunately the new file has the same #US stream contents as the original.

It seems I didn't get the idea how the Writer works. Studying the sources is not easy as dnlib consists of quite a lot source files and lines.

The [dnlib documentation](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) refers to [ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx) - obfuscator that uses dnlib to manipulate files. However, looking at its sources, it seems that it doesn't manipulate the #US heap at all.

Comment: Post an issue on the github page.

Comment: @simonatrcl I notified the dnlib author via e-mail. I'm not sure if it is appropriate to fill in an "official" dnlib issue. The problem is that dnlib is underdocumented but that's understandable in case of open source project developed and maintained by one programmer.

Comment: If he's put it on github, then I's say it's appropriate - Issues are part of it, after all. Might be worth doing that as well as emailing - last checkin was 9 months ago and the email might have changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before calling module.Write(), initialize a writer options class. Set the listener to your writer listener and then pass in the options to Write(). After certain writer events you can then start manipulating the metadata before it gets written to the file. You can then add arbitrary strings to the #US heap or any other heap.

There's an example you can look at: https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/master/Examples/Example6.cs

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. It seems I can rewrite high-level information immediately after the module is loaded: `ModuleDefMD.Load("test.dll").GetTypes().ElementAt(1).Methods.ElementAt(0).Name = "xyz";` but the low level rewrite needs `OnWriterEvent()` because the raw data are not accessible at `ModuleDefMD` "level". Can you please confirm that or elabore more?